# Facing Bad Gateway 502 error while uploading cookbook to CHEF Server

Tags: chef-infra

[root@rhel6 cookbooks]# knife cookbook upload iis-tutorial-1

```
ERROR: bad gateway
Response: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.2.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `chef-server-ctl status` say on the Chef server? Also check `/var/log/chef-server` there.

Comment: I've seen that error when chef server is under heavy load. Is it a transient problem?